# Grammar excluding repetition of qualifiers

Tags: c, parsing

I'm currently reading through [Compiler Design in C.](http://www.holub.com/software/compiler.design.in.c.html) I'm not too familiar with the concept of grammars, but the first exercise asks that i write a grammar that recognizes a C variable declaration.

My question is, how would I prevent(in the grammar) the repetition of signed and unsigned? My familiarity of productions(as the book teaches) has a single nonterminal on the left, pointing to up to two terminal / nonterminals. I'm just not sure how the language can be used to "see" if another symbol has already been used.!

My grammar thus far is:

```
Declaration -> Attributes Identifier  
Attributes -> Prefix Type  
Prefix ->
```

Is there not a more succinct way than "qualifier > unsigned long | signed long | unsigned " etc etc? it would get very long when you include all possible combinations, and even then doesn't appear transferable as a prefix, since one can put qualifiers anywhere.

Comment: It would be easier to discuss about a snippet of code you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent repetition by coding combinatorially enumerative sets of grammar rules that disallow it.  You can do this for very small sets of optional or unordered items like "signed" and "unsigned", sort of practically.

It isn't worth the trouble.

You could also consider writing your grammar to prevent a given variable declaration from occurring twice in the same scope.  This is essentially the same problem, but it should be pretty clear that it is hopeless to do this by just giant sets of grammar rules.

The issue is that most languages are context-sensitive, e.g, what you can write in one place, depends on what you wrote somewhere else,  perhaps far away in the source text.  (Your problem with signed and unsigned has "far away" being as small as 1 token).  But our grammar formalisms are mostly for context-free (and in fact, for many parser generators, even less that that, eg. LL or LALR) languages.  So they simply are not expressive enough to describe *all* the constraints that a language places on the text you write.

There's a standard cure for this.  You write a grammar, that accepts "too much", and implement a procedural post-parsing pass that checks the additional constraints.  Since the "procedural" part is typically implemented in a conventional programming language, it is Turing-powerful and you can thus always code checks for the context-sensitivity, if it is possible to check.

To have a post-parsing pass, your parser has to remember what it saw.  Thus you get the need for parse-capture, typically done with abstract syntax trees.  Checking the validity of names in scopes requires you have symbol tables.  Verifying that the parts of your Java program are always reachable requires at least simple flow analysis.

Bottom line:  write your grammar simply.  Don't worry about such repetition; it is easily checked post-parsing. Get past the parsing bit; it is the easiest part of the problem.  Be prepared to add lots more machinery to make processing the grammar practical.  Most people don't seem to understand this. (Check my bio for a discussion of "Life After Parsing").

Answer (score 1):

You can encode the "state" of your expression by using a series of productions.  Something like:

```
Expr -> "unsigned" AfterSignExpr
Expr -> "signed" AfterSignExpr
Expr -> AfterSignExpr

AfterSignExpr -> "char" AfterTypeExpr
AfterSignExpr -> "short" AfterTypeExpr
AfterSignExpr -> "int" AfterTypeExpr
AfterSignExpr -> "long" AfterTypeExpr

AfterTypeExpr -> Identifier "," AfterTypeExpr
AfterTypeExpr -> Identifier ";"
```

Although a C declaration is considerably more complicated because it allows for modifiers all over the place, in different orders, function declarations, struct declarations, etc.

Spoiler alert: [here](http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html) is an actual C11 YACC grammar (and associated lexer).  Have fun trying to wrap your head around that!